# How to build a matrix from a dataframe based on the values of a specific column?

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have a dataframe named `df` as follows:

```
Genes         ID          Type 
CFH         MB-0002       Gain 
CFHR3       MB-0002       Gain 
DEFB131     MB-0003       Gain 
UNC93B5     MB-0003       Loss 
CCDC125     MB-0004       Loss 
CCNB1       MB-0002       Gain
CFH         MB-0004       Loss
CCNB1       MB-0003       Gain
```

I want to build a matrix, say `Mat`, and write it into a `csv` file where I will have the Genes as rows and the `IDs` as columns. I want to put:

- `1` if the corresponding type is `Gain`
- `-1` if the corresponding type is `Loss`
- `0` in all other places.

And example of my matrix would be:

```
                MB-0002 MB-0003 MB-0004
   CFH              1       0      -1
   CFHR3            1       0       0
   DEFB131          0       1       0
   UNC93B5          0      -1       0
   CCDC125          0       0      -1
   CCNB1            1       1       0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
xtabs(c(1L, -1L)[Type] ~ ., data=df)
#         ID
#Genes     MB-0002 MB-0003 MB-0004
#  CCDC125       0       0      -1
#  CCNB1         1       1       0
#  CFH           1       0      -1
#  CFHR3         1       0       0
#  DEFB131       0       1       0
#  UNC93B5       0      -1       0
```

`xtab()` is similar to `table()` except that it takes a variable containing the frequency counts for each combination of levels.  You can convert the result back to a data-frame with `as.data.frame()`.

The left-hand side of the formula gives the "counts" (in this case the values that the contingency table is to be populated with).  It uses a known trick to convert a factor to a numeric vector using indexing (see `?factor`).  The `.` on right-hand side is a short-cut for "the rest of the variables in the data-frame", which in this case is equivalent to `Genes + ID`.

Comment: Actually the needed explanation is the LHS expression. I stared at it for longer than I usually need for R code. It's cute but probably a bit obscure for the new R user.

Comment: @ernest-a 

Thanks. It's working.
However, I tried the following code:   

`for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
   if(df$Type[i]=='Gain'){
     Mat[df$Genes[i], df$ID[i]] <- '1'
   }else if (df$Type[i]=='Loss'){
     Mat[df$Genes[i], df$ID[i]] <- '-1'
   }
 }`  
But it is showing the following error:  

`Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, df$Genes[i], df$ID[i], value = "-1") : 
  subscript out of bounds`.  

Can anyone tell what is the reason?

Comment: @rawr No, I used the answer. I was just curious why my code is not working.